# Loop for matrix resampling in R

Tags: r, loops, sample, resampling

I have a dataset with five variables and 1500 observations and want to do resampling 1000 times. The dataset looks like:

```
      K_Ri K_Le D_Ri D_Le Goal
[1,]    1    0    1    0    1   
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0   
[3,]    1    0    0    1    1   
[4,]    0    0    1    0    1   
[5,]    1    0    0    1    1
```

... etc.

It is about soccer, so that K_Ri means Kicker kicked the ball to the right of the goal, G_Ri means Goalkeeper jumped to the right etc.

However, I also defined a 3x3 matrix that shows all possible actions from goalkeeper and kicker (Right/Right, Right/Centre, Right/Left etc.) and their payoff regarding chosen action (Payoff=(sum of total balls kicked to a certain direction - stopped balls kicked to that direction) / sum of total balls kicked to a certain direction).

So, I need to define such a loop that would both do samples for my dataset and automatically create payoff-matrix for these samples.

My code so far is...

```
Y=cbind(as.matrix(soccer))
boot=Y[sample(x=nrow(Y),300,replace=TRUE),]
samplefunct=function(X=dll.data){boot=Y[sample(x=nrow(Y),300,replace=TRUE),]}
replicate=replicate(1000,samplefunct())
```

I would be really glad if somebody can help me!

Ivan

Comment: What is wrong with your code? It looks you are resampling with `replicate` (wrapper to `sapply`).

Comment: It works , but only for the "raw" dataset and not for the payoff-matrix. I need to get a payoff-matrix that is based on the resampled dataset (1000 times :) ) in order to calculate KI for each of 9 outcomes of the payoff-matrix.

Comment: So, you have a function that calculates the payoff matrix based on the data? What is it called? Or is that the problem?

Comment: That is actually the problem. I can do it manually 1000 times for each resample , but want it to get programmed with loop.

Comment: `TM=matrix(c(sum(D_Ri==1&K_Ri==1),sum(D_Ri==1&K_Ri==0&K_Le==0),sum(D_Ri==1&K_Le==1),sum(D_Ri==0&D_Le==0&K_Ri==1),sum(D_Ri==0&D_Le==0&K_Ri==0&K_Le==0),sum(D_Ri==0&D_Le==0&K_Le==1),sum(D_Le==1&K_Ri==1),sum(D_Le==1&K_Ri==0&K_Le==0),sum(D_Le==1&K_Le==1)),3,3)` Here is how I defined the matrix with total outcome. To get the payoff matrix, I also defined a matrix with stopped balls (TMstop) and applied simple subtraction and division:    (TM-TMstop /TM)